# common lisp how can I make my variable act as the operator it holds when it is first in list?

Tags: common-lisp

So I am very new to lisp, and not that advanced of a programmer yet. Just getting started really.

I'm messing around trying to get a very simple genetic algorithm going from scratch, and while most of my code seems to execute as desired, I'm stuck with such a simple bug/misunderstanding that I am blocked from the bottom... There is clearly something I am not getting despite my hours online trying to find a solution..

Basically, I know it has something to do with the fact I am trying to call a variable as if it were an operator (which the variable holds) and thus it tells me my function (which is really just a variable holding an operator) is not defined.

The start of my code works fine.

```
(defvar *nb* 8)
(defvar *random-operators* '(+ - * /))
(defun get-operator ()
  "Returns an element of the list of operators chosen at random."
  (nth (random (length  *random-operators*)) *random-operators*))
```

So `(get-operator)` does get me one of the four random operators, as desired.

I used this even simpler code to test the structure of my code, and it works as desired.

```
(defun ga-simple ()
  "Returns the value of genome once it matches *nb* and prints
the number of generations required."
  (do ((genome (random 10) (random 10))
       (generation-counter 1 (incf generation-counter)))
      ((eql genome *nb*)
       (format t
               "The solution is ~S, and it took ~D generations"
               genome
               generation-counter))))
```

The problem comes when I try and create a genome composed of three variables, one holding the operator, and the other two, the integers.

```
(defun ga-with-operator ()
  (do ((genome 42 (opr1 int1 int2))
       (generation-counter 0 (incf generation-counter))
       (opr1 + (get-operator)
       (int1 (random 10) (random 10))
       (int2 (random 10) (random 10))
      ((eql genome *nb*)
       (format t
               "The solution is ~S, and it took ~D generations"
               genome
               generation-counter))))
```

my compiler warnings tell me where the problem is...

```
;Compiler warnings for "./ga-one.lisp" :
;   In GA-WITH-OPERATOR: Unused lexical variable OPR1
;Compiler warnings for "./ga-one.lisp" :
;   In GA-WITH-OPERATOR: Undefined function OPR1/
```

And so clearly a call to the function `(ga-with-operator)` says opr1 is an undefined-function-call. So from what I gather when the "do" macro checks the increment condition for the variable genome, it reads the list, expecting opr1 to be an operator and not a variable holding an operator... Now, an operator simply entered works perfect here, but I don't know how to make lisp use the evaluated value of opr1, which is an operator, as the operator for the integers...

To simplify, I made a function trying to construct a single genome using my get-operator function, and failed hard even there lol

```
(defun get-genome ()
 (let ((operator1 (get-operator)))
   (operator1 (random 10) (random 10))))
```

So I made a test-let function to make sure my "let" variable assignment is right...

```
(defun test-let ()
  (let ((rand (get-operator)))
    (print rand)))
```

Which it does... So now I am getting desperate and missing something obviously very simple and yet crucial to make it all stick together.

If someone could explain to me, or just show me, how to get the simple `(get-genome)` function to work I would really appreciate it. I know lisp expects an operator as the first element in the list, and my error stems from me feeding it a variable holding an operator instead... How do I convince it my variable is the operator it is holding?

in case anyone wants to know the working code...

```
(defvar *nb* 42)

(defvar *random-operators* '(+ - * /))

(defun get-operator ()
  "Return an element of the list of operators chosen at random."
  (nth (random (length  *random-operators*)) *random-operators*))

(defun get-genome ()
 (let ((operator1 (get-operator)))
   (funcall operator1 (+ 1 (random 9)) (+ 1 (random 9)))))

(defun ga-with-operator ()
  (do ((genome (get-genome) (get-genome))
       (generation-counter 0 (1+ generation-counter)))
      ((eql genome *nb*)
       (format t "The solution is ~S, and it took ~D generations"
               genome generation-counter))))
```

Comment: You seem to be looking for `apply`. I could not find an exact duplicate, although there are many similar questions on StackOverflow.

Comment: -1 not to discourage you from asking more questions, but because the question is so overwhelming for an essentially trivial problem and therefore is unlikely to help future visitors.

Comment: (defun get-genome ()
     (let ((operator1 (get-operator)))
     (funcall operator1 (random 10) (random 10))))

Comment: this is my first time asking a question, so it's cool, i appreciate the feedback and will try and be more direct i guess. And thanks tripleee i appreciate the answer. apply works on a list though, so I found that funcall simply works thanks to your lead. :-/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Common Lisp you need to use `FUNCALL` if the function is returned by a function or if the function is stored in a variable.

```
(defun get-genome ()
 (let ((operator1 (get-operator)))
   (funcall operator1 (random 10) (random 10))))
```

Common Lisp has different namespaces for functions and for values. Thus a name can both be a variable and a function:

```
(defun foo (list)
  (list list list))
```

The first `list` in the last line calls the global function called `list` and the second and third are actually the local variable `list`.

```
(defun ga-with-operator ()
  (do ((genome 42 (opr1 int1 int2))
       (generation-counter 0 (incf generation-counter))
       (opr1 + (get-operator)
       (int1 (random 10) (random 10))
       (int2 (random 10) (random 10))
      ((eql genome *nb*)
       (format t
               "The solution is ~S, and it took ~D generations"
               genome
               generation-counter))))
```

Above function has more problems.

- Can you see the first? Hint: try indenting it correctly. Are the parentheses correct?
- also: `+` is not a function. It is a variable in your code. To make it a function you would need to quote or *function quote* it. `'+` or `#'+`.
- you also don't need to `INCF` the `generation-counter`. Just adding `1` is fine. The `DO` loop updates the variable. Use `(1+ generation-counter)`.

Comment: Thanks I appreciate it. Helped a lot.lisp is kinda weird and yet so cool.(defun ga-with-operator ()
  (do ((genome (get-genome) (get-genome))
       (generation-counter 1 (1+ generation-counter)))
        ((eql genome *nb*) (format t "The solution is ~S, and it took ~D generations" genome generation-counter))))

Comment: ok, first day here... so no code in comments.. aight well thanks and sry for the mess, i'll catch on eventually.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, `FUNCALL` / `APPLY` is what you want, but just to complete the picture, note that this also works:

```
(setf (symbol-function 'operator1) (get-operator))
(operator1 (+ 1 (random 9)) (+ 1 (random 9)))
```

The reason you generally don't want to do this is that binding of the symbol-function slot is global.