# Calling a list of functions in Common Lisp

Tags: clojure, common-lisp, lisp-2

In Clojure, I can define a sequence of functions, then call them like they'd been any other value, as so:

```lisp
(doseq [op [+ - * /]]
  (println (op 1 2 3 4)))
```

which produces the following output:

```
10
-8
24
1/24
nil
```

Trying to do the same in Common Lisp results in nothing but error:

```lisp
(dolist (op '(+ - * /))
  (print (op 1 2 3 4))

; in: DOLIST (OP '(+ - * /))
;     (LET ((OP (TRULY-THE (MEMBER / * - +) (CAR #:N-LIST671))))
;       (SETQ #:N-LIST671 (CDR #:N-LIST671))
;       (TAGBODY (PRINT (OP 1 2 3 4))))
; 
; caught STYLE-WARNING:
;   The variable OP is defined but never used.

; in: DOLIST (OP '(+ - * /))
;     (OP 1 2 3 4)
; 
; caught STYLE-WARNING:
;   undefined function: OP
; 
; compilation unit finished
;   Undefined function:
;     OP
;   caught 2 STYLE-WARNING conditions

debugger invoked on a UNDEFINED-FUNCTION:
  The function COMMON-LISP-USER::OP is undefined.

Type HELP for debugger help, or (SB-EXT:EXIT) to exit from SBCL.

restarts (invokable by number or by possibly-abbreviated name):
  0: [ABORT] Exit debugger, returning to top level.

("undefined function")
```

Calling `op` as `#'op` didn't work for me either.

So is there a way to do this in CL?

Comment: Have a look at [common lisp how can I make my variable act as the operator it holds when it is first in list?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25221343/1281433)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the namespace for functions and the namespace for data are separate in LISP-2 (and hence in common-lisp), you need to use `funcall` when passing functions as parameters:

```
(dolist (op '(+ - * /)) 
   (print (funcall op 1 2 3 4))))
```

`funcall` function is an roughly equivalent of Clojure's `apply`, and will apply the `op` function to the provided parameters. In this case there's one more thing going on, since `op` is a symbol bound to a function, but `funcall` takes care of that.